# jquery tabs bind tabsselect or tabsshow not fired

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling

I have problem with jquery tabs. If I bind to tabsselect or tabsshow events of tabs, they are not fired.

I am using latest jquery-ui 1.10.3 and there are no js errors in my webapp console.

Code:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
  alert(ui.index); // This is never displayed
  if (ui.index === 1 && plot1._drawCount === 0) {
    plot1.replot();
  }
  else if (ui.index === 2 && plot2._drawCount === 0) {
    plot2.replot();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The event is [activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)

```
$("#tabs").on('tabsactivate', function(event, ui) {
  var index = ui.newTab.index();
  alert(index); // This is never displayed
  if (ui.index === 1 && plot1._drawCount === 0) {
    plot1.replot();
  }
  else if (ui.index === 2 && plot2._drawCount === 0) {
    plot2.replot();
  }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wJhPP/)

Comment: Do not use bind, use on or off
$("#tabs").on('tabsactivate', function(event, ui) {

Comment: The ui.index is undefined. We should look into ``ui.newTab.index();`` instead.